# Periodic Task in Background

Tags: android, android-service

I'm currently building an app that starts a session by sending a request to the backend. After that, the app has to send a heartbeat request every 4.5 minutes. If the app does not send a request to the backend after 4.5 minutes since the last successful request, the session will get terminated. The heartbeat request can be sent earlier which also means that the next heartbeat has to be sent 4.5 minutes after that request.
Once the user has started the session, he should be able to put the app to the background to use the device for other things.

I'm struggling with coming up with a solution that works with the background restrictions (doze mode, etc).

I'm currently running the app with a foreground service. But the requests stop after a couple of minutes if I don't use the device actively. I tried the WorkManager and the AlarmManager. But the requests keep getting delayed.

I played around with `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` and this seems to work but I don't want to use that approach since Google seems to really dislike apps using this permission.

I created a test app to play around with different approaches. Maybe I'm doing something completely wrong?

Service:

```
class MainService : Service() {

    private lateinit var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            val appName = getString(R.string.app_name)
            val channelName = "$appName channel name"
            val channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channelDescription = "$appName channel description"
            createNotificationChannel(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, channelImportance, channelDescription)
        }
        val notification = createOngoingNotification(this, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, "Content Text")
        startForeground(1000, notification)

        wakeLock = (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag").apply {
                acquire(1 * 60 * 60 * 1000L)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        intent?.action?.let {
            if (it == "Heartbeat") {
                val v = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
                }
            }
        }
        setNext()
        return START_STICKY
    }


    private fun setNext() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainService::class.java)
            intent.action = "Heartbeat"
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 1000, pendingIntent)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true)
        wakeLock.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    companion object {

        const val REQUEST_CODE = 101
        const val NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE = 100
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "notification_channel_id"

        fun createOngoingNotification(context: Context, requestCode: Int, icon: Int, text: String): Notification {
            val contentIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            val contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
                .build()
        }


        @RequiresApi(api = 26)
        fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context,
                                      id: String, name: String, importance: Int,
                                      description: String) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)
            channel.description = description
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why is it a problem if the session ends when the device is not being used? BTW google dislikes you requesting user to disable optimizations with that intent, but you can send them to settings and let them disable it manually. That's fine

Comment: If you use the foreground service, do you acquire WAKE LOCK and WIFI LOCK?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Because the user might want to use the device after 15 minutes again and I don't want the user to have to restart the session every time he stops using the device for a couple of minutes. The user also gets notified by SMS if the session has been terminated and I don't want the user to get spammed.

Comment: @DerekK Wake locks are ignored by doze mode

Comment: But your app is not affected by doze if you use foreground service.

Comment: @DerekK Well somehow my app is affected by something. I created a test app to play around to find a solution. I implemented a foreground service that vibrates every 5 seconds and the vibrating stops like 40 seconds after I put the app in background and locked the screen.

Comment: Show code of your test app if you can

Comment: @DerekK I edited my question and added the code of my service

Comment: System might ignore repeating alarms. Replace Alarm Manager with Handler.postDelayed or TimerTask for tests. Also show how do you start the service (Activity)

Comment: @DerekK Handler.postDelayed and TimerTask both stop after about 15 seconds of locked screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194003/discussion-between-derek-k-and-chris-parker).

Answer (score 0):

I think that foreground service may be stopped as you are not executing anything inside it after you set the alarm. Foreground service keeps running if you are using it, so for making it work periodically i would put an observable that emits a value every 5 seconds for example. You only need the one emmited after 4.5 minutes but that will keep the foreground service active until you need it. Using rxjava:

```
Observable.intervalRange( 0 , 54, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
        .doOnNext{
          //You may not need this 
        }
        .doOnComplete {
            //heartbeat
            //start this observable again for other 4.5 minutes
        }
```

You will emit a value every 5 seconds 54 times. 54x5 = 270 seconds (what is 4.5 minutes)